# Why does Java 8 ZonedDateTime think 24:01 is a valid time string representation?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I need to get two ZonedDateTime instances representing the beginning and the end of the current week.

```
ZonedDateTime currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime startOfThisWeek = currentDateTime.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plusMinutes(1);
ZonedDateTime endOfThisWeek = startOfThisWeek.plusDays(6);
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm");
String startweek = startOfThisWeek.format(df);
String endweek = endOfThisWeek.format(df);
System.out.println(startweek);
System.out.println(endweek);
```

Output:

```
2018-06-18 24:01
2018-06-24 24:01
```

What does this string represent? Is it 1 minute after midnight, morning of 2018-06-18? If so, why is 24:01 a valid time? I thought it should be 00:01 in a 24 hour clock representation.

Edit: and is there a way to format this to show 00:01 instead without transforming the string into a new string?

Comment: _why is 24:01 a valid time?_ ... Strictly speaking, it's just not part of a standard, however [it is occasionally used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock), and [Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Japan#Time) uses it if an activity spans across that time barrier (anecdotally, I've had plane tickets flying into Japan that had the arrival time as 25:15)

Comment: For illustration purpose, see this [diagram](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PlainTime.html#CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY) showing the meaning of hour 24 in context of pattern symbol "k".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Change formatting pattern from `kk` to `HH`.
- Your addition of one minute is irrelevant.

> 2018-06-18 24:01

…becomes:

> 2018-06-18 00:01

Tip: When debugging, use the default standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format in generating a `String`.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
)
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS )
.with( 
    TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-06-18T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

## `k` = 1-24 hour (actually, 24-23)

The [deleted Answer by Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50938563/642706) was correct: You are using `k` which is documented as representing the time-of-day using a 24-hour clock running from 1 to 24.

What is not so clear in the doc is that the first hour is counted as 24, rather than 0. So it might be better stated to say that the day runs from 24-23, that is, `24, 1, 2, 3, … , 22, 23`. The value `24` represents the first hour of the day, not the last.

Here is a simple example using time-of-day only to demonstrate this behavior.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "kk:mm" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.MIN;
String output = lt.format( f );

System.out.println( lt.toString() );  // Standard ISO 8601 format, 00-24.
System.out.println( output );         // `kk` format is 24, 1 , 2, … , 22 , 23.
```

> 00:00
>
> 24:00

Note that this `kk` behavior of *java.time* where the entire first hour of the day is labeled `24` in unusual, non-standard, and not commonly used. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Times_after_24:00). Apparently, this style is used occasionally in some special contexts where business hours extend beyond midnight such as broadcasting.

As for what you expected…

> it should be 00:01 in a 24 hour clock representation.

If you want 0-23, use "H", [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true).

First, look at the default [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted output.

```
ZonedDateTime currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime startOfThisWeek = currentDateTime.with( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS ).plusMinutes( 1 );
ZonedDateTime endOfThisWeek = startOfThisWeek.plusDays( 6 );
System.out.println( startOfThisWeek );
System.out.println( endOfThisWeek );
```

> 2018-06-18T00:01-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> 2018-06-24T00:01-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Now, your custom format. Change your formatting pattern from `kk` to `HH`.

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" );
String startweek = startOfThisWeek.format( df );
String endweek = endOfThisWeek.format( df );
System.out.println( startweek );
System.out.println( endweek );
```

> 2018-06-18 00:01
>
> 2018-06-24 00:01

## Week

Some other notes…

If you are trying to represent the week, there is no need to add a minute. The generally best practice in representing a span-of-time is the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a week starts at the first moment of one Monday and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the following Monday.

Also, I recommend always passing a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) explicitly to `now` even if that be [`ZoneId.systemDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) to make your intentions crystal-clear.

Adjusting to Monday has the issue of what to do if today is already a Monday. Use either of this pair of [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementations found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to specify your choice of behavior:

- [`previous( DayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previous(java.time.DayOfWeek))
- [`previousOrSame( DayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previousOrSame(java.time.DayOfWeek))

Example code.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;  // Or `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.
ZonedDateTime weekStart = now.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS ).with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
ZonedDateTime weekStop = weekStart.plusWeeks( 1L ) ;
```

For tracing and debugging, always generate a String representing the value of your date-time objects using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format rather than a custom format as seen your Question. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default in their `toString` methods.

```
String outputStart = weekStart.toString() ;
String outputStop = weekStop.toString() ;
```

> 2018-06-18T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]
>
> 2018-06-25T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

If you want date-only values, use the `LocalDateTime`.

You can represent your time range in a single object using the `LocalDateRange` or `Interval` classes found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

Last tip: Let *java.time* do the heavy-lifting by using `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` methods to automatically localize the generated strings using a specified `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms of formatting.

Comment: @Gilbert For database work, you should be exchanging smart objects with your database rather than dumb strings. As of JDBC 4.2 you can directly exchange *java.time* objects. Use `Instant`, to switch into UTC rather than your particular zone.  `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , zdt.toInstant() )` & `Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class );`  then `ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ); ` The code in your Question is ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. Search Stack Overflow for much more info and examples.

Comment: _What is not so clear in the doc is that the first hour is counted as 24, rather than 0._ .. [not exactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock): `The notation 24:00 mainly serves to refer to the exact end of a day in a time interval. ... Similarly, some railway timetables show 00:00 as departure time and 24:00 as arrival time.`

Comment: @txtechhelp What [you refer to in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) is *not* the behavior shown here by `kk` in *java.time*. Your reference is discussing `24:00` as a synonym for `00:00` – just that one moment, not the entire hour. Re-read your citation to see that `24:00` marks the *end* of the day, e.g. "00:00–24:00". In that context a minute later is always `00:01`. In contrast, the `kk` behavior in Java is different, referring to the entire first hour of the *new* day with `24`, so a minute later would be `24:01`. Very different behavior.

Comment: @txtechhelp That Wikipedia page actually explains that labeling the entire first hour of the day as `24` (like the *java.time* `kk` behavior) is uncommon and non-standard. Apparently, this style is used occasionally in some special contexts where business hours extend beyond midnight such as broadcasting. I added a note about this in my Answer. The bizarre variations and tricks-of-the-trade in date-time handling never cease to amaze me.